# Sending data to plugin

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have created my modified path planner based on carrot_planner. But for creating a plan I need some aditional information that I get from some rostopic. Generally you create nod in main and register your subscriber tehre, but as far as I know it is impossible to create main function inside plugin.

Is there a way I could listen to some topic from inside a plugin? Or any other way I could send my plan from (example:) "my_makeplan.cpp" to my "plugin my_navigator"?
Where my_makeplan.cpp would be regular executable with main().

EDIT: here is my initialize method, strangely if I write publisher there is no error while compiling, but I don't see them in I write rostopic list.
If I add subscriber I get this error:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const char [5], int, )’

Here is my initialize method:

```
    void MyNavigator::my_plan(const nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid::ConstPtr& msg){

    }
    
  void MyNavigator::initialize(std::string name, costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros){
    if(!initialized_){
      costmap_ros_ = costmap_ros;
      ros::NodeHandle private_nh("~/" + name);
      private_nh.param("step_size", step_size_, costmap_ros_->getResolution());
      private_nh.param("min_dist_from_robot", min_dist_from_robot_, 0.10);
      costmap_ros_->getCostmapCopy(costmap_);
      world_model_ = new base_local_planner::CostmapModel(costmap_); 
      //we'll get the parameters for the robot radius from the costmap we're associated with
      inscribed_radius_ = costmap_ros_->getInscribedRadius();
      circumscribed_radius_ = costmap_ros_->getCircumscribedRadius();
      footprint_spec_ = costmap_ros_->getRobotFootprint();

      initialized_ = true;

            ros::Subscriber sub1 = private_nh.subscribe("/map",1,my_plan);
            ros::Publisher pub1 = private_nh.advertise<nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid> ("moja_mapa", 1);
            ros::Publisher path_publisher1 = private_nh.advertise<nav_msgs::Path> ("moj_plan_path", 1);

    }
    else
      ROS_WARN("This planner has already been initialized... doing nothing");
  }
```

and here is my .h file (without includes):

```
namespace my_navigator
{
    class MyNavigator : public nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner
        {
            public:
                MyNavigator();
                MyNavigator(std::string name, costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros);
                void initialize(std::string name, costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros);
                bool makePlan(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& start, 
          const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& goal, std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>& plan);
                void my_plan(const nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid::ConstPtr& msg);
            private:
                costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros_;
                double step_size_, min_dist_from_robot_;
                costmap_2d::Costmap2D costmap_;
                base_local_planner::WorldModel* world_model_;
                double inscribed_radius_, circumscribed_radius_, inflation_radius_;
                double footprintCost(double x_i, double y_i, double theta_i);
                std::vector<geometry_msgs::Point> footprint_spec_;
                bool initialized_;
        };

};

#endif
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39537/sending-data-to-plugin/) by [Febo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2891/febo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2012-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Generally, in C++ you create a class that contains subscribers and publishers which are initialized in the constructor. You can subscribe to topics and read ROS parameters either in your plugin's constructor or in the (virtual) method `initialize`.

**Edit**: The problem with your code is that the `NodeHandle` and the subscribers and publishers are local to your init method. As soon as this method exits, the stack is unwound and the objects destructed. Make them member variables of your class and everything should work.

I actually don't think your subscriber works as expected. The compiler should complain unless you have a global method `my_plan` somewhere. To use `my_plan` of your class, you need to pass a class instance:

```
sub1 = private_nh.subscribe("/map", 1, &MyNavigator::my_plan, this);
```

Alternatively you can use `boost::bind`. You can find more information on callbacks [here](http://ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Callback_Signature).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4